# Find offset in struct

Tags: c, struct

I have struct in c

```
struct Book {
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
};

struct Book * book;
```

I can access the integer `book_id` like `book->book_id`

But how can I access to book_id by offset? How can I calc (in c code) the offset of specific element in struct and access like  `book+X`

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html

Comment: First "I can access to book_id like book->book_id". No you can't, because `book` isn't a pointer. As for "access like book+X"... You can't. Not directly anyway. You can get the *byte* offset to a member, but to get a pointer to the member you need a pointer to the first *byte* of the structure. And you *must* know the exact type of each member.

Comment: And more importantly, what is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? *Why* do you need to access the members through offsets? Right now your question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please ask about the actual problem you're trying to solve instead, and add a note about this as a possible solution. We can then help you better, and possibly by giving you a better solution to the original problem. *Or* if it's just curiosity, then that's okay. But then please [edit] your question to state that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define offset(type, member)  ((size_t)&(((type *)0) -> member))
#define ACCESS(object, type, offset)  (type *)(((char *)&(object)) + (offset))

typedef struct
{
    int a,b,c;
}t;

int main(void)
{
    t s = {1,2,3};
    printf("%zu\n", offset(t,b));
    printf("%d\n", *ACCESS(s, int, offset(t,b)));
}
```

Comment: why a #define offset(type, member) after closing bracket of main?

Comment: copy paste error

Comment: Why not use [the standard `offsetof` macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) instead?

Comment: just wanted to show how it works - see  my comment